# Place all text in quotes into ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, parsing, arraylist

I'm looking for an easy way to take a string and have all values in quotes placed into an ArrayList

Eg

```
The "car" was "faster" than the "other"
```

I would like to have an ArrayList that contains

```
car, faster, other
```

I think I might need to use RegEx for this but I'm wondering if there is another simpler way.

Comment: Can there be nested quotes?

Comment: There will be no nested quotes in any string I'll be parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex, it is actually quite easy. Note: this solution supposes that there cannot be nested quotes:

```
private static final Pattern QUOTED = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");

// ...
public List<String> getQuotedWords(final String input)
{
    // Note: Java 7 type inference used; in Java 6, use new ArrayList<String>()
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    final Matcher m = QUOTED.matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        ret.add(m.group(1));
    return ret;
}
```

The regex is:

```
"           # find a quote, followed by
([^"]+)     # one or more characters not being a quote, captured, followed by
"           # a quote
```

Of course, since this is in a Java string quotes need to be quoted... Hence the Java string for this regex: `"\"([^\"]+)\""`.

Comment: Thanks for the code!  When I try to use QUOTED eclipse complains about the RegEx string "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Comment: Uh? Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about... Note that it is private **static** final; which means it must be declared at the class leve, not in the method.

Comment: Also, the code is Java 7; see the comment I added in the edit

Comment: Ah, yeah, my bad I placed it in the wrong spot.  Works perfect!!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script to parse the input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "The \"car\" was \"faster\" than the \"other\"";
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        output.add(matcher.group().replaceAll("\"",""));
    }
}
```

Output list contains:

```
[car,faster,other]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache common String Utils [substringsBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method

```
String[] arr = StringUtils.substringsBetween(input, "\"", "\"");
List<String> = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: And what is `StringUtils`?

Comment: @fge: To answer your edited comment. I have already added link to the answer.

Comment: OK, but there is no need for Apache commons there ;) Note: I am not the downvoter

Comment: @downvoter: Could you please enlighten me with the reason behind the reward?

Comment: @fge: I prefer commons wherever possible (because of lazy nature may be). Not a problem with downvote just curious to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Well, when it comes to a utility library, I have long ago abandoned commons in favor of Guava...